# CakePHP slow response on SQL Server find

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp, cakephp-2.7

I have a problem with my app in CakePHP 2.7.1, with Sqlserver Datasource.

When I do a `find` operation on any table, the response time is extremely slow (more than 1 minute).

I did the research with XDebug + QCachegrind and I found out that the problem is `Sqlserver->listSources()`, which lists all the 1385 tables on the database.

This is the shortened code (core file lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\Database\Sqlserver.php:172)

```
public function listSources($data = null) {
    $result = $this->_execute("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES");
    while ($line = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
        $tables[] = $line[0];
    }
    return $tables;
}
```

I put a simple `microtime` benchmark around the `while` block and nearly all the process time is taken by these 3 lines.

Is there any way to speed up this?

Is there any way to tell CakePHP not to do the `listSources` process?

Comment: You need to look into caching the results at a very low level, so that there isn't a lot of overhead there to deal with. APC, Memcached, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Open

```
./Lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Sqlserver.php
```

Find this text

```
PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL
```

Change to

```
PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY
```

When i tried that in my cakephp mssql speed increased 50% even 100%

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have exactly same case.

Comment: Wow, my connection was too slow, simple operations was taking about minutes to perform and this solved my problem. I think CakePHP must implement a way to chose which cursor to use as it is REALLY RELEVANT to speed of your script, thanks!

Comment: I confirm I got a 100% increase in speed.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the shortened code

The [not-shortened code](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Sqlserver.php#L166-L192) is much more relevant:

```
public function listSources($data = null) {
    $cache = parent::listSources();
    if ($cache !== null) { 
        return $cache; # <-
    }
    $result = $this->_execute("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES");
    if (!$result) {
        $result->closeCursor();
        return array();
    }
    $tables = array();
    while ($line = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
        $tables[] = $line[0];
    }
    $result->closeCursor();
    parent::listSources($tables); # <-
    return $tables;
}
```

The [parent method](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DataSource.php#L89-L113) only populates the cache (in the `_cake_model_` cache config), the default cache time in production mode [is 999 days](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7/app/Config/core.php#L356) and in development [it's ten seconds](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7/app/Config/core.php#L358). Given the description you're currently in development mode - recognise that (whilst pretty inconvenient) it's basically a development-environment problem.

There are a couple of solutions, but the simplest by far is to just cache the data for longer, and irrespective of debug/production mode. To do so just change the [relevant cache config](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7/app/Config/core.php#L376-L386):

```
Cache::config('_cake_model_', array(
    ...
    'duration' => '+999 days' # <-
));
```

If there's a schema change you'll need to remember to clear the cache, otherwise your app won't know about it.

The much-more-intrusive solution (overriding model `schema` and `setSource`, hardcoding the model schemas so the app doesn't have to query the db to know) would remove the calls to `listSources` altogether; but at the significant inconvenience/cost of you needing to manage your model schemas - worth pursuing if this delay is a problem, and not if it isn't.